# Doctrine/Symfony 2: Entities with too many relationships

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm working with Entity objects from Doctrine queries and i end up with a very big array, with all information from all entities related. This ends up being a huge data tree... how can i limit this? Avoid listing all data from all relationships?

Comment: I don't know if it helps but you could try doing `->getResult(Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY)` at the end of a query, the Results will be returned as an array

Answer (score 1):

You can always remove not needed associations (this is a best practice for speeding up Doctrine). Or you can select only fields that you need in your presentation layer (as read-only data):

```
public function getAll()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u'); // Where are in User custom repository

    return $qb
        ->select(array('u.id', 'u.first', 'u.last'))
        ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
}
```

If you still need to work with objects (or for complex queries that needs plain SQL) a possibility is filling only needed properties (and eventually, associations/nested collections) of your domain object.

An example, more on [native SQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/native-sql.html#resultsetmappingbuilder):

```
public function getAll()
{
    $mapping = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping();

    $mapping->addEntityResult('Acme\HelloBundle\User', 'e');

    $mapping->addFieldResult('e', 'id', 'id');
    $mapping->addFieldResult('e', 'first', 'first');
    $mapping->addFieldResult('e', 'last', 'last');

    $sql = "SELECT id, first, last FROM user ";

    $result = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $mapping)->getResult();

    // Or hust return $result itself (array)
    return new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection($result);
}
```

Of course the disadvance (?) is use of native SQL. I don't believe that `ResultSetMapping` can be used with DQL.

**EDIT**: take a look at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/best-practices.html

Comment: I'm looking for a simple way to disable lazy loading in Doctrine, or, get a maximum depth of relationship. Is it possible?

Comment: @vinnylinux if i recall it correctly, lazy loading is when you select a subset of data and then, when accessing properties or associations not loaded, doctrine will load (at an additional query) all data for you. So lazy loading is a good thing. As i said, it depends. What's data is used for?

Comment: It's definitely not a good thing when you're serializing data with something like JMSSerializer bundle. Test yourself with a reasonably large data set with various relationships. It's starts to recurse.

Comment: @vinnylinux never worked with that bundle, i trust you. Can't simply fetch only needed fields?